# js regexp variable parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parentheses

So I have a function that receives an argument (named`c`), then I create a regular expression like so: `regC = new RegExp(c,'gi')`. Now this works fine for most characters, but my function can also receive a `(` or other paretheses. This cases create an error.
I tried this: `regC = '/['+c+']/gi'`, but it didn't work

Comment: We are **not** a code writing service. Please refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried to do any research? What have you tried? Questions here should have a clear problem/question, with research shown, and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the character set `'['+c+']'`  to `RegExp` functions as

```
regC = new RegExp('['+c+']','gi');
```

Because

```
regC = '/['+c+']/gi'
```

Makes a string

Comment: @AndréDion `c` is a variable that can take even `(` as mentioned in the question

Comment: oh yeah, I worded that poorly. Edited now